# TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.firestore is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Just trying to set it up firebase for the first time and I get these errors cant find any right answer to work this is my config

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import {
  initializeApp
}
from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x"
};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebase.firestore();
export {
  db
};
```

the error I get -
TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.firestore is not a function

it shows to the line
const db = firebase.firestore();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the `compat` version of firestore you need to initialize the `firebaseApp` also with the `compat` version. I would recommend using the new SDK version for both:

```js
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "x",
  authDomain: "x",
  projectId: "x",
  storageBucket: "x",
  messagingSenderId: "x",
  appId: "x",
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore();
export { db };
```

With the new SDK, you actually don't need such a file like before where you initialize your app and create the database instances. After you initialize your app with the new SDK you can just call `getFirestore()` without the need to have the `firebaseApp` for it. `getFirestore()` will automatically use the default app.

A realtime listener by using `collection` would look like this:

```js
import { collection, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(collection(db, "cities"), () => {
  // Respond to data
  // ...
});

// Later ...

// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

When you read the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) make sure to switch to the SDK 9 version:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!, and what to do if i get the same error when i try to use "collections"

Comment: Can you pls show me how you use `colletions`

Comment: useEffect(()=> {
    db.collection('todos').onSnapShot(snapshot => {
      setTodos(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data().todo))
    })
  },[]);

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line of your code:

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

for this:

```
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
```

This way you'll be using compatability api in both imports